# How to use C# serialization to serialize to a very custom format

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to use C#'s builtin serialization capabilities to serialize the following class:

```
public class DevicePolicy
{
    public enum SharingLevel
    {
        Unrestricted,
        Blocked
    }

    public SharingLevel SHARING_LEVEL = SharingLevel.Blocked;
    public bool REQUIRES_AUTHENTICATION = false;
    public List<string> MANAGED_LIST = new List<string>();
}
```

To this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
  <string name="SHARING_LEVEL">BLOCKED</string>
  <boolean name="REQUIRES_AUTHENTICATION" value="false" />
  <set name="MANAGED_LIST">
    <string>blah</string>
  </set>
</map>
```

NOTE: I don't control what the Xml looks like because it is being consumed by something else that I can't change.  So I have to match this exactly.

I'm having difficulty doing this and I'm starting to wonder if it would be better to just write my own SerializeXml and DeserializeXml methods instead if trying to make C#'s builtin serialization work with such a custom format.

If someone knows of an easy way to do this I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: are you familiar with decorating a class with `[Serializable]` attribute..?

Comment: Yes, but maybe not as much as I need to be, my difficulty is that if I do that I still can't seem to get it to match this xml.  The three types here are the three examples of variables I need to match.

Comment: you could always generate your own based on specific data that you are getting where is the data coming from , generated from and or read from..?

Comment: The xml file is coming from an Android preferences file for Android apps.  So it is generated from an Android app.  Are you saying use C#'s tool which creates a class based on the xml?

Comment: I am saying based on the data that you are reading generate your own XML which matches the xml format you are needing it to be in since you said it changes now I am wondering what the changes are or differences.. try looking for consistencies vs non and code for the non as well as those that have data in same common format

Comment: FYI, this is not "C# built in serialization". It is the XML Serialization feature of .NET. It is not specific to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need something that custom you may have to just bite the bullet and have your class implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to do a custom serialization. Here is a example that serializes the `SharingLevel` object, I leave the rest for you to do.

```
public class DevicePolicy : IXmlSerializable
{
    public enum SharingLevel
    {
        Unrestricted,
        Blocked
    }

    public SharingLevel SHARING_LEVEL = SharingLevel.Blocked;
    public bool REQUIRES_AUTHENTICATION = false;
    public List<string> MANAGED_LIST = new List<string>();

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //TODO
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        //Root
        writer.WriteStartElement("map");

        //The element for "SharingLevel SHARING_LEVEL"
        writer.WriteStartElement("string");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "SHARING_LEVEL");
        writer.WriteString(SHARING_LEVEL.ToString().ToUpperInvariant());
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        //The element for "bool REQUIRES_AUTHENTICATION"
        writer.WriteStartElement("boolean");
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not aware I could implement of 'IXmlSerializable' this gives me a solution that still works nicely with C# but allows me a more custom solution than before.  Still a lot of work but at least it will work nicely with things when done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via DataContractAttribute or use LINQ to XML. Just google in this directions.
I think LINQ to XML should be simplest solution for this.

Comment: After looking at DataContractAttribute it seems that it only allows me to specify the name of an element and not that it has an attribute with a specific value and where the vale of the element goes.  Also not sure this solves the List<string> variable either.